# ERROR namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running hadoop in pseudo distributed mode on an ubuntu VM.  I recently decided to increase the RAM and number of cores available to my VM, and that seems to have completely screwed hdfs.  First, it was in safemode and I manually released that using:

hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

Then I ran:

hadoop fsck -blocks

and practically every block was corrupt or missing.  So I figured, this is just for my learning, I deleted everything in "/user/msknapp" and everything in "/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/mapred/mapred/.settings".  So the block errors were gone.  Then I try:

hadoop fs -put myfile myfile

and get (abridged):

```
    12/01/07 15:05:29 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/msknapp/myfile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:653)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
12/01/07 15:05:29 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
12/01/07 15:05:29 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/msknapp/myfile" - Aborting...
put: java.io.IOException: File /user/msknapp/myfile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
12/01/07 15:05:29 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /user/msknapp/myfile : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/msknapp/myfile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:653)
    at ...

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/msknapp/myfile could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:653)
    at ...
```

So I tried to stop and restart the namenode and datanode. No luck:

hadoop namenode

```
    12/01/07 15:13:47 ERROR namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/dfs/name/image/fsimage (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.isConversionNeeded(FSImage.java:683)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage.checkConversionNeeded(Storage.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage.access$000(Storage.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1248)
12/01/07 15:13:47 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/dfs/name/image/fsimage (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.isConversionNeeded(FSImage.java:683)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage.checkConversionNeeded(Storage.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage.access$000(Storage.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1248)

12/01/07 15:13:47 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Would somebody please help me out here?  I have been trying to fix this for hours.

Comment: by the way, "hadoop dfsadmin -format" results in this:  ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot remove current directory: /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/dfs/name/current

Comment: I even uninstalled all of hadoop and reinstalled it, and I still have this same error.  It looks like I will be forced to delete the VM and start a fresh one.  This is one mighty nasty bug.

Answer (score 6):

Go into where you have configured the hdfs. delete everything there, format namenode and you are good to go. It usually happens if you don't shut down your cluster properly!

Comment: Now it seems to be using my local file system instead of hdfs for actions.  Can you explain to me the "correct" way to shut down my cluster?  I did not even know it needed to be shutdown a specific way.  If you power off your VM, does that mean the cluster will not shutdown properly?

Comment: So when you start it up, with "start-all.sh" it starts the jobtacker the namennode and all other daemons that are running the cluster. In order to shut it down correctly, you need to issue "stop-all.sh" command and this will carefully shut down everything.  i recommend you close it down, erase the location where your hdfs was initiated do a "hadoop namenode -format" and then reboot the cluster. Let me know if this works!

Comment: I had a similar issue, where I mistakenly started namenode process from root user, later realised I should have done it from hduser, so stopped it, and then tried again to format from hduser and faced similar issue.. Got it resolved after seeing your answer, thanks a lot! 1 UP!

Answer (score 0):

Following error means, fsimage file not have permission

```
namenode.NameNode: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/dfs/name/image/fsimage (Permission denied)
```

so give permission to fsimage file,

$chmod -R 777 fsimage